# Can't get Ubuntu to boot on Macbook

Tags: boot, wireless, macbook-pro

I am trying to do a clean single boot install on a late 2013 MacBook Pro retina.  I have installed a new OWC 1.0TB Aura Pro X2 SSD. Many folks on YouTube make it look so easy but I have also used Mint, POP and fedora. They all install fine and run from the thumb drive but once installed and booted I get the dreaded file icon with a question mark flashing. Also no wifi drivers.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product and release details; are you hoping we'll guess?  Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices, with 5 different installers available (via selection of ISO), but you've not told us what you tried?